# Import Sonar 3.4.1 analysis results to SonarQube 5.2

Tags: sonarqube

I setup a new server and installed SonarQube 5.2. Now I want to import the results of my other Sonar 3.4.1 server. Problem is that my old Sonar works with an MySQL database and the new version with Oracle db.

Is there a way to import the results to my new SonarQube instance?

Answer (score 2):

That should happen automatically when you follow the [upgrade procedures](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)

Comment: Yes, but I had to setup the new version 5.2 on a different server. "Update" mabye was a misleading word for this. 
Then I must search for another way to do this update.

Comment: Try editing your question to more fully & accurately describe the situation, @JannickHerrmann